# C++ file (exe) reading itself

Tags: c++, binary, fstream

I would like to my binary file to read itself, but I'm having some trouble. Right now this is what I got:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    char data[1000];
    std::fstream file(argv[0], std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
    file >> data;

    std::cout << data;

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

This only prints the first 3 characters, for some reason... that's it. I don't know why it isn't reading the whole file. Any help?

Comment: Aside from what other have pointed out, please note that you _shall_ set the size of the underlying array when using formatted input with a `char` array! When you do `file >> data;` without having set `file.width()` there is a potential for a buffer overrun if the read doesn't stop before the size of the array is exhausted! Ideally, you'd avoid using formatted input to `char` arrays directly and rather use a `std::string`. Of course, the answer to your actual question is that the third byte is interpreted as a space and you'd use unformatted input instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some value in the file causes the stream input to end too early, e.g. a \n

Try something like

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    char data[1000];
    std::ifstream file(argv[0], std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
    int i = 0; 
    while (file.get(data[i])
    {
       i++;
       if (i == 1000) break;
    }

    for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        std::cout << std::hex << data[j];

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: Updated after comment from OP

In C++ you should avoid c-style arrays. Use a vector instead. A vector has dynamic size and can grow when needed.

```
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    char c;
    vector<char> data;
    std::ifstream file(argv[0], std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
    while (file.get(c)
    {
       data.push_back(c);
    }

    for (auto t : data)  // for each ...
    {
        std::cout << std::hex << t;
    }

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks that really helped. One more thing, right now the code is only reading the first 1000 bytes, how can I read the entire file? I've tried some things, but since the char array needs a constant (hard-coded) value I really don't know how to do this.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to read an executable unformatted, as well as opening it as binary. Use good old fread; a filebuf is superficially attractive, but it will still invoke locale conversions which you don't want.

Comment: `fstream.read()` is unformatted like `filebuf`, but they both still have the locale and facet character conversion stuff going on.  Indeed it's best to stick with `fopen` and `fread`.

Comment: @benvoight aah! Good to know. I've only ever used it for unformatted text.

Answer (score 2):

The C++ `operator >> (const char *)` stream function is only for C-style strings. It's not suitable for arbitrary binary data. You'll need to decide what you want the output to look like and write code to output raw, arbitrary binary data in your desired format.

You also need to keep reading. And you need to use a read function that won't overrun your buffer.